# Why does the loop for checking primes use Math.sqrt to determine the max number of times to run the loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, numbers, primes

```
function isPrime(n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return false;

    let max = sqrt(n);

    for(let i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (n % i === 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Why does this code block use the square root of the number to be checked as the index of the loop to be run thus making i, the square root of the number in question, to go no higher than say a quarter responses. Are none of the numbers above the square root of n capable of diving evenly into the number? Even big ones into the thousands.

Comment: If there's a number larger than the square root that divides the test number, then there must also be a number *smaller* than the square root that divides the number.

Comment: 25 is 5*5. 36 is 6*6. If you're checking *any* number [25, 36] would you ever check 7*7?

Comment: Another way to say it is that after the square root you will simply be returning the inverse of the divisors found before it.